# Sequelize on cascade delete run a function?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, cascade

I have 2 models MenuItems and Category, with a 1-n relation from category to menuitem. Also, whenever a MenuItem is created, a .jpg file is saved on the server (filename is generated by server, so no need to save it as a column in the database). I have

```
{
    onDelete: "cascade"
}
```

set in the Category assosciation, because if a category is deleted then all the menu items should go with it. However, this leaves a bunch of unused .jpg files. Is there any way to delete them when the cascade deletion occurs?

Answer (score 1):

You can add beforeDestroy hook for MenuItems model, like below:

```
// in menuItemsModel.js
MenuItems.beforeDestroy((instance, options) => {
  console.log('MenuItems before destroy hook is triggered')
  const imageFileDestination = instance.getDataValue('imageUrlFieldName')
  // put your logic to delete .jpg files with destination
  fs.unlink(url)
})
```